# How to disable automatic capitalization in Windows 10's Mail app?

Tags: windows-10, autocorrect, regional-settings, windows-mail

I have disabled autocorrect in Windows' Typing settings:

[image: Screenshot of disabled autocorrect settings in Windows 10's Settings]

When I write an e-mail in English and include some French sentences, random lowercase words become capitalized automatically, as if they were at the start of a sentence. The capitalization usually doesn't make sense, and I haven't found the setting that prevents it.

Here's an example. I wrote the sentence as shown, except that I didn't capitalize "Nouvelles":

[image: Wrongly capitalized sentence]

I am fine with these few sentences not being spellchecked correctly, but I want them to be capitalized as I wrote them.

How can I disable this automatic capitalization for all languages?